# How can I change the wireless name of my computer?

Tags: networking, wireless, device-name

How can I change the name of my PC that the router sees when I'm connected 
(in attached devices)?
(Without changing username)

Edit (clarification): Currently, when I connect my laptop wirelessly to a router, it's possible to see my computer's name (an thus my own name, since it's `<myname>-XPS-13-9343`) via the attached devices screen in the router configuration panel. I want to change the way that my computer is seen to the outside world (for shake of privacy).

Comment: What would you like it to be? What does it show currently? What is the hostname of your computer configured to be now (run `hostname` to see)?

Comment: It's currently `<myname>-XPS-13-9343`. I dont want it to include my name.

Comment: Why the negative rank?

Comment: Please update your question with all the info asked for. It's not possible to tell whether this question is even on topic from the current amount of info in it. It seems like you are asking how to configure your router, rather than Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Your pc name is saved in /etc/hostname & /etc/hosts files.
On a Terminal, type `sudo gedit /etc/hostname` command and change the pc name.
Also, change the hostname in `sudo gedit /etc/hosts` "first line is 127.0.0.1 localhost , second line is 127.0.0.1 "YOUR PC NAME".
Then type this command `sudo service hostname restart` to restart the service. your PC name is changed.

Comment: `sudo hostname newname` will change the hostname to newname. You don't need to edit the hostname and hosts files to do so. This also doesn't mean the router will use it as the name. That depends on the router itself.